# Construct ZipInputStream from BufferedInputStream or not

Tags: java, inputstream

I see that ZipInputStream is inherited from InflaterInputStream. The latter has an internal buffer.

Most code examples I see construct a new ZipInputStream the following way:

```
File f = new File("myfile");
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedInputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(fs);
ZipInputStream zs = new ZipInputStream(bs);
```

I read that subclasses from InflaterInputStream needn't be constructed from a BufferedInputStream, because they are buffered themselves. Is this correct? And what would be the recommended way to construct a ZipInputStream?

Maybe a bit of context, the zip files I am reading range from a few KB to a few MB in size.

Comment: Another nice question ... and welcome to upvote levels ;-)

Comment: You can try to use [zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm)